# load CoreData in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I try to load all data from CoreData into my TableView. But why do I load every data value 5 times?

```
var value: [String] = []  

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contacts")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let result: [AnyObject] = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
            for res in result {
                value.append(res.valueForKey("name") as! String)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to load context: \(error)")
        }
        return value.count
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If I add the objects 'Test' and 'Test1' I get the following result:

1. Test
2. Test1
3. Test
4. Test1
5. Test
6. Test1
7. Test
8. Test1
9. Test

10.Test1

Thank's for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you show the code where you add `Test` and `Test1` to CoreData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numberOfRowsInSection` method can be called multiple times when the tableView is loaded (and thereafter).  Each time it is called, you append the values to your array - hence the duplicate values.

Put the code that builds the array into `viewDidLoad` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're working far too hard. `NSFetchedResultsController` exists precisely for the task of putting Core Data into a tableview.